# Python-specific PATH environment variable?

Tags: python, shell

Say I have a script `script.py` located in a specific folder in my system. This folder is not available on `PATH`.

Assuming that I will **always** run `script.py` using `python script.py`, is there **any way** to run my script from anywhere on the system **without** having to modify `PATH`?

I thought modifying `PYTHONPATH` would do it, but it doesn't. `PYTHONPATH` seems to only affect the module search path, and not the script search path. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct, `PYTHONPATH` does not affect script search path. You can create an env var `MY_SCRIPT=/full/path/to/script.py` and then run `python "$MY_SCRIPT"` wherever you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, add it to your `PYTHONPATH` as you are doing, but you cannot invoke it with `python foo.py`, instead, use `python -m foo`.